# Qual fazer para chamar uma função de outro controller no Laravel? Gostaria de implementar a melhor prática

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mvc, controller

Tenho um controller boletosController necessito chamar a function create na negociacaoController;

boletosController.php;

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Repositorios\Boletos;  
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

    class BoletosController extends Controller
    {
        protected $boletos;

        public function __construct(Boletos $boletos)
        {

            $this->boletos = $boletos;
        }


        public function create($data)
        {

            $create = $this->boletos->create($data);
            return $create;
        }

    }
```

Qual a melhor forma para chamar a função create no controller negociacaoController:

negociacaoController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Models\Boletos;
    use App\Models\Negotiation;


    class NegociacaoController extends Controller
    {

        public function index()
        {

         }


       public function gerarBoletosNegociacao()
        {

         //chamar aqui uma função de outro controller


         }
```

Comment: A melhor forma é não chamar. Se o seu controller possui uma responsabilidade maior do que apenas tratar a requisição http, então tem coisa errada. A lógica deveria estar implementada em outra estrutura, geralmente chamada de service.

Comment: Por exemplo, por que não chama o método `create` do seu repositório ao invez de chamar do controller?

Comment: Então nesse caso eu teria que inverter, chamar a model de Negociacao e tratar dentro do controller que gera os boletos?

Comment: Como já foi falado aqui nos comentários, aparentemente tem coisa errada ai, o correto é você criar um `Service` e colocar essa função nele, e depois você "injeta" como dependência o serviço nos 2 controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Eu concordo com o posicionamento do @AndersonCarlosWoss. Você deve implementar usando outra estrutura. Vou estender o argumento dele; os controllers no MVC podem ser uma espécie de service ou façade.. porque eles podem orquestram chamadas a outras lógicas e estruturas, como acesso a banco de dados e regras de negócio em si.

O que acontece é que muitas pessoas fazem regras de negócio diretamente no controller. Mas ai você me pergunta, o controller não é o lugar das regras? Sim, regras de resposta a interface. Não necessariamente são regras de negócio ou regras de acesso a dados. Pode ser que em estruturas simples, você chame o banco de dados diretamente dali... mas em softwares mais robustos ou melhor elaborados, mais complexos, você vai chamar suas classes e suas regras de negócio dali e não criá-las ali dentro do controller.

Isso server para o Larvel e qualquer outra tecnologia, estamos falando de arquitetura de componentes.

Recomendo:

1. **Coesão e Acoplamento**, pra você entender princípios de responsabilidade  https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-coesao-e-acoplamento/18538
2. **Um pattern estrutural**: Facade. pra tentar compartilhar a visão que o controller do mvc pode ser um método que não necessariamente concentra regras de negócio. https://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern
3. **Um pouco de arquitetura orientada a componentes**, pra você usar os princípios de responsabilidade criando componentes que podem ser invocados em diferentes momentos e até arquiteturas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering

Observação sobre a model:
Complementando, o rapaz aí pediu para você fazer diretamente na Model. Isso não é legal, pois a model no MVC pode ser uma representação da sua estrutura do banco de dados. Isso é o comum de aprender por aí, mas não é uma verdade absoluta, pois ela está mais para ser uma representação da estrutura de dados que será apresentada do que ser a estrutura de dados que é armazenada. Muitas vezes as interfaces mostram informações que tem origem de dados diferentes, com suas estruturas diferentes.